# How can I use Ionic Pull to refresh

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My controller:

```
.controller('ECtrl', function($scope, EService){

    $scope.events = []; // init events as empty array
    EService.getAll().then(function (response) {
      $scope.events = response;
      console.log($scope.events);

    $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $scope.events.push('Incoming todo ' + Math.random());
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    $scope.$apply()
  };
})
```

console : Uncaught TypeError: $scope.events.push is not a function

{{ event.conteudo }}

```
   <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
 </ion-item>
```

I already tried to solve this problem but til now nothing
so I want to know How can bind the $scope.events from my controller with a doRefresh() function?
please I need a example code.
thanks

Comment: In [Ionic](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/pull-to-refresh/) website they have mentioned how to do it. There is one [example](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/mqolp) too hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you please post your html code as well?

Comment: Hi there, I need help to edit my content I added HTML content but I can't see it.

Answer (score 3):

In your template put it inside

```
<ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh" on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
```

In conteroller

```
$scope.doRefresh = function() {
   // here refresh data code
   $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
   $scope.$apply()
};
```

[more info](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/pull-to-refresh/)

Comment: Please show me How can bind the $scope.events from my controller with a doRefresh() function